# Execute windows .exe using PHP

Tags: php

Please help me that how can execute windows .exe in PHP with input and output CSV file as parameters and return the result in output CSV file? I have no idea about its functionality.

Comment: Thanx for suggestion @Labradorcode. but i want execute with input and output CSV file as parameters and return the result in output CSV file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shell_exec` to run the exe file. Which takes `command` as the parameter.

```
$output = shell_exec("sample.exe <param1> <param2>");
```

Here `param1` and `param2` are the parameter/file path which exe accepts.

Refer this document [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

Comment: But i want execute with input and output CSV file as parameters and return the result in output CSV file. Is it possible?

Comment: @AmarjeetSingh I just modified the answer. Try this out.

Comment: Ok thank you @Vinay Patil

Answer (score 0):

```
$answer = shell_exec("absolute path to exe file");
echo $answer."</br>";
```

Comment: But i want execute with input and output CSV file as parameters and return the result in output CSV file. Is it possible?

Comment: $answer = shell_exec("absolute path to exe file  $arguements");
echo $answer."</br>";

About handling the csv that you have to handle in the exe program thats written